# Why full outer join returns less results than join?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have two sql in netezza:

1.

```
SELECT T1.Col1, T2.Col2 FROM TableA T1 JOIN TableB T2 ON T1.Col3 = T2.Col3
```

2.

```
SELECT T1.Col1, T2.Col2 FROM TableA T1 FULL OUTER JOIN TableB T2 ON T1.Col3 = T2.Col3
```

I assume that 2 should return more or equal results as 1. However, results from 1 is more than 2.

Could someone help me understand why?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, at least as far as I understand the different joins. [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins).

Comment: That's very odd. Your assumption is correct. Can you show input and output data, and you actual query? *I* assume your actual query is a bit more complex and you might have misinterpreted it.